# Suffixes / terminaisons diminutifs en français

Tags: suffixes, morphologie

Quelle est la signification du suffixe dans *Cendrillon*=*cendre* + ? S'agit-il d'un suffixe diminutif ?

Les diminutifs existent dans plusieurs langues. Ils sont notamment assez répandus dans les langues romanes, telles que l'italien, le portugais et l'espagnol - existaient-ils en français (avant d'être largement remplacés par la construction *le/la petit(e) + nom* ? ([L'article Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutif#Fran%C3%A7ais) indique quelques diminutifs français dont l'utilisation est assez restreinte.)

Comment: On peut dire que ce suffixe est péjoratif en le rapprochant de deux autres termes péjoratifs désignant une femme : "**une souillon**" (une femme dont la maison et/ou la personne sont très mal tenus) ou "**un laideron**" (une jeune fille laide)

Comment: Voici une liste de diminuitifs en français: https://www.jerevise.fr/suffixe-diminutif.html aigle/aiglon, par exemple